# libtool searches for standard libs (stdc++) at GCC installation directory ignoring all other - how to fix?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, libtool

I've got GCC which is located at non-default path.
All environment and search path's are correct. If I build not using libtool everything is Ok.
But all projects using libtool can't find libstc++.la because it has been searched at GCC installation path.
How can I work it around? How can I force libtool to search for standard libraries at custom path?